# How to list all users of posted in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, list, author

```
$args  = array(
'orderby' => 'display_name'
);
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();
if (!empty($authors))
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($authors as $author)
    {
        $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);
        echo '<li>'.$author->ID.' '.$author_info->first_name.' '.$author_info->last_name.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo 'No authors found';
}
```

I'm using post filter by post author. Above code displays all the users so need to display only authors who posted in the blog.

just like wp_list_authors() function but i need to get the author id intead of author name. because I need to create a dropdown list. While someone change the option, then I need to get the post by that author in AJAX

Comment: What is in your `$post->post_author` ?

Comment: I dont want to get author by getting all posts. just get the author who are all posting under particular blog like wp_list_authors.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_users you can query authors only, other than that loop all posts to build your ids, but this is resource heavy, cache!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 1:

Hope this help:

```
$posted = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type',
]);
$author_ids = [];
foreach ($posted as $post) {
    $author_ids[] = $post->post_author;
}
$author_ids = array_unique($author_ids);
if (!empty($author_ids) )
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($author_ids as $user_id)
    {
        $author_info = get_userdata($user_id);
        echo '<li>'.$user_id.' '.$author_info->first_name.' '.$author_info->last_name.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo 'No authors found';
}
```

Make sure to change `post_type` to your post type and each user has both `first_name` and `last_name`.

---

There's a missing argument on Codex reference: `has_published_posts`.

```
$args = [
  'orderby' => 'display_name',
  'has_published_posts' => true
];
$authors = new WP_User_Query($args);
...
```

It's better to look for inside class file because info on Codex is not always up-to-date.

Comment: This sounds good! I need published post user of particular post type but not all

Comment: @AbdulRahumanM You need to update your question. What **users of posted** and **only authors who posted** meant? What is your `post_type`?

Comment: to display the user who posted the post(post type = custom post types)

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped me :-)